# Boost get_untyped_deleter error

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, smart-pointers

Every time I compile my code with g++ in ubuntu I get this error:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:453:26: error: ‘class boost::detail::sp_counted_base’ has no member named ‘get_untyped_deleter’

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.async_wait(&print);

  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

and the way I run it is this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

I am running boost 1.55 (the latest to this date)
What is going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's g++ version? Are you sure you don't mix different Boost versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem seem to be a conflict between the already installed Boost 1.49 (which another program had installed in my computer) and Boost 1.55.
I uninstalled Boost 1.55 and left 1.49 and now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Igor R’s comment, it is very likely that you have ended up with only a partial installation of boost on your box, and you either have missing files or gcc ends up taking bits and pieces from different paths, according to its standard includes.

If you run `g++ -H main.cpp -o main` you should be able to track down what’s happening with that particular include. For example:

```
$ g++ -H -c main.cpp -o main 2>&1 | grep sp_counted
............. /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp
.............. /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp
............. /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp
```

As you can see, on my box, it takes everything from the standard include path, which is incidentally what I expect and is the default boost (for me it isn’t 1.55).

And if I wanted to point my g++ to a specific boost version I could just use `-I` to override the default preferences,

```
$ g++ -H -c main.cpp -o main -I/opt/dev/boost_1_55_0 2>&1 | grep sp_counted
............ /opt/dev/boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp
............. /opt/dev/boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp
............ /opt/dev/boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp
```